# Android trouble with layout horizontal wrapping

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having trouble getting content to fill width with the following layout.

When i add stuff to contentPane it always acts as wrap_content regardless of what the child itself has specified. I have tried changing gravity to fill and the result is the same. What am i missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+bottom_button_panel/root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+bottom_button_panel/contentPane"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        style="@style/buttonPanel">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+bottom_button_panel/leftAlignedButtons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+bottom_button_panel/centerAlignedButtons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+bottom_button_panel/rightAlignedButtons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

make `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` of all your layouts.

Comment: i am trying to get it to fill width not height

Comment: remove android:gravity="fill_horizontal",
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"   ,android:layout_alignParentTop="true" for everylayout and check or tel exactly what do you want?

Comment: `fill_parent` has been deprecated in favour of `match_parent`.